# Replace list value by reference

Tags: c#

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class Organization
{
    public List<IJob> Jobs { get; set; }
    public IJob BigBoss { get; set; }

    public Organization()
    {
        BigBoss = new Doctor();

        Jobs = new List<IJob>
        {
            BigBoss,
            new Doctor(),
            new Doctor()
        };
    }
}
```

If I set the BigBoss property to a new value, I would like that value to be updated in the list as well. After BigBoss is pointing to something new, the first item in the list should as well. I know that the following code won't do that in C# because of the way C# works with references:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Organization();

        test.BigBoss = new Developer();
        //test.Jobs[0] is still pointing to a Doctor, not a Developer
        Console.WriteLine(test.Jobs[0]);
    }
```

Is there some other clean way of doing this?

Comment: Something like `public IJob BigBoss { get { return Jobs[0]; set { Jobs[0]=value; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Jobs[0]` is reference to `BigBoss = new Doctor();` when you call the constructor `new Organization();`

When you change:  `test.BigBoss = new Developer();`
Your BigBoss is refer to `Developer` but Jobs[0] still refer to the old BigBoss.

You can change your Organization like this:

```
public class Organization
{
    public List<IJob> Jobs { get; set; }
    private IJob bigBoss;
    public IJob BigBoss { get {return Jobs[0];} set { Jobs[0] = value; } }

    public Organization()
    {       
        bigBoss = new Doctor();     
        Jobs = new List<IJob>
        {
            bigBoss,
            new Doctor(),
            new Doctor()
        };          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the property setter of `BigBoss` to manipulate the Jobs. Then return the `BigBoss` by `Jobs[0]` in the getter.